# Android development, help can't get ADB interface drivers working for Motorola XT5

Tags: android

I have tried to get the ADB interface drivers working for motorola XT5 but have had no success.

I have windows 7 amd x64,
installed google USB driver package, revision 4 (installed via android SDK and AVD manager)
I am new to android

Is this even possible to get working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes got it working!

had to connect phone as a modem

added the following lines to android_winusb.inf

%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0489&PID_C001
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0489&PID_C001&MI_01

Comment: Unfortunately break points don't work so I will be using AVD if my code crashes.